The simplest spring security config breaks my working spring-boot app
I have a working spring boot application with unit tests that work.
If I add ANY configuration for spring security no pages can be served it just tries to serve static content the controller is never called!
even this config will result in no calls to a controller:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll());
    return http.build();
}

The full log of a simple test:
02-04-2024 14:59:43,791 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@615e83ac, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4438938e, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@25e8e59, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7e18ced7, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@4e50ae56, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@1e120628, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5773d271, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@50a7c72b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@54c11750, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1c68d0db, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5d5d3a5c, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@4ebd6fd6]] (1/1)

02-04-2024 14:59:43,792 +0100 DEBUG o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Securing GET /login
02-04-2024 14:59:43,792 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
02-04-2024 14:59:43,793 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
02-04-2024 14:59:43,793 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
02-04-2024 14:59:43,794 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
02-04-2024 14:59:43,795 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Invoking CorsFilter (5/12)
02-04-2024 14:59:43,795 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Invoking CsrfFilter (6/12)
02-04-2024 14:59:43,796 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.c.CsrfFilter [cfg-Test worker] Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [Ant [pattern='/logon/**']]]]
02-04-2024 14:59:43,796 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Invoking LogoutFilter (7/12)
02-04-2024 14:59:43,796 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.l.LogoutFilter [cfg-Test worker] Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
02-04-2024 14:59:43,796 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/12)
02-04-2024 14:59:43,796 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache [cfg-Test worker] matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
02-04-2024 14:59:43,797 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/12)
02-04-2024 14:59:43,797 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/12)
02-04-2024 14:59:43,797 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
02-04-2024 14:59:43,797 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
02-04-2024 14:59:43,798 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager [cfg-Test worker] Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@2674ca88]
02-04-2024 14:59:43,798 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager [cfg-Test worker] Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@2674ca88] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda/0x00007f94405089f8@430212cb
02-04-2024 14:59:43,798 +0100 DEBUG o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Secured GET /login
02-04-2024 14:59:43,800 +0100 TRACE o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [cfg-Test worker] Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]] and 3 interceptors
02-04-2024 14:59:43,803 +0100 DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler [cfg-Test worker] Resource not found
02-04-2024 14:59:43,806 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter [cfg-Test worker] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
02-04-2024 14:59:43,806 +0100 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver [cfg-Test worker] Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource login.]
02-04-2024 14:59:43,806 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository [cfg-Test worker] No HttpSession currently exists
02-04-2024 14:59:43,806 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext [cfg-Test worker] Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
02-04-2024 14:59:43,806 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext [cfg-Test worker] Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
02-04-2024 14:59:43,807 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [cfg-Test worker] Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]

MockHttpServletRequest:
  HTTP Method = GET
  Request URI = /login
   Parameters = {}
      Headers = []
         Body = null
Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
         Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
    Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
         Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException

ModelAndView:
    View name = null
         View = null
        Model = null

FlashMap:
   Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
       Status = 404
Error message = No static resource login.
      Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
 Content type = null
         Body = 
Forwarded URL = null

Redirected URL = null
Cookies = []
Status
Expected :200
Actual   :404

I have tried many things over the easter break, but none have worked.
If I remove the spring security EVER THING WORKS, add it back and with no other changes and app will not start and all tests fail.
Started on Windows 10 now on Suse Linux Leap 15.5 running under JDK 21, Gradel 8.6, IntelliJ.
Just don't understand how adding a security config can stop the app from working without a security failure!
Must have done something wrong somewhere, no idea where or where to start looking.
The source code is just over 6MB.
Any suggestions?

It seems like your SecurityFilterChain is not loaded; see first line of logging Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain.  Is your SecurityConfiguration loaded?

Thanks that gives me something new to investigate.

After many more hours of searching and resorting to a 'poke and hope' strategy problem is resolved which is good. But the downside of 'poke and hope' is that you are never sure which poke or combination thereof solved the issue as some of the pokes could be completely ineffective which is why its always a last resort.
